# url_to_absolute query

Tags: php

right, i am building a web crawler and there is a section of my code which translates to absolute urls instead of /macbookpro/ to http://www.apple.com/macbookpro. but when i echo my code, it only prints one result, which is the first link it sees why. Do i have to create an array, because when i did, i echoed the array and listed was the word 'Array'

```
   <?php
require_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('url_to_absolute/url_to_absolute.php');

          $URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  
// grabs the urls from URL 
          $file  = file_get_html($URL);
           foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement) {
          $links = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);
        } 
  echo $links;
    ?>
```

Comment: Use [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) if you want to display the contents of an array.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump your array, it gives you a text representation of your objects. It will show you the array and it's elements. Echo is more for just outputting strings. you could loop your array and echo each element, but if you just want to see it, var_dump is the answer.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build an array in `$links` You need to do

```
$links[] = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);
```

Right now, you are overriding the value of `$links` with each loop iteration.

You should also decalre `$links = array();` somewhere before your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('url_to_absolute/url_to_absolute.php');

$links = Array();
$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  
// grabs the urls from URL 
$file  = file_get_html($URL);
foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement) {
   $links[] = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);
} 
print_r($links);
```

So you'll need to init the array, add to it with [] and finally use something suitable to actually print it out, such as print_r.

Comment: how would i add that to a mysql database, so that each link is on a unique row?

Comment: umm... check out some mysql + php tutorials for that.